# Simple tee example

Tags: linux, shell, tee

Can someone please explain why tee works here:

```
echo "testtext" | tee file1 > file2
```

My understanding was that tee duplicates the input and prints 1 to screen.

The above example allows the output from echo to be sent to 2 files, the first redirecting to the second.

I would expect 'testtext' to be printed to screen and passed through file1 and landing in file2. Similar as to how the text in the following example would only end up in file2.

```
echo "testtext" > file1 > file2
```

Can anyone explain what i am missing in my understanding?

Edit

Is it because its writing to file and then to stdout which gets redirected?

Comment: What does it mean for text to pass "through" a file?

Comment: For your reference, you can see how to use tee with examples  https://grizzlybit.info/blog/how-to-use-tee-on-linux

Answer (score 4):

Your description is right: tee receives data from stdin and writes it both into file and stdout. But when you redirect tee's stdout into another file, there is obviously nothing written into terminal because the data ended up inside the second file.

> Is it because its writing to file and then to stdout which gets redirected?

Exactly.

What you are trying to do could be done like this (demonstrating how tee works):

```
$ echo "testtext" | tee file1 | tee file2
testtext
```

But since tee from gnu coreutils accepts several output files to be specified, one can do just:

```
$ echo "testtext" | tee file1 file2
testtext
```

But your idea of *passed through file1 and landing in file2* is not correct. Your shell example:

```
echo "testtext" > file1 > file2
```

makes the shell open both files `file1` and `file2` for writing which effectively truncates them and since stdout can be only redirected into another file directly, only the last redirection is effective (as it overrides the previous ones).

Answer (score 3):

`tee` writes its input to each of the files named in its arguments (it can take more than one) as well as to standard output. The example could also be written

```
echo "testtext" | tee file1 file2 > /dev/null
```

where you explicitly write to the two files, then ignore what goes to standard output, rather than redirecting standard output to one of the files.

The `> file2` in the command you showed does not somehow "extract" what was written to `file1`, leaving standard output to be written to the screen. Rather, `> file2` instructs the shell to pass a file handle opened on `file2` (rather than the terminal) to `tee` for it to use as standard output.

Answer (score 1):

"is it because its writing to file and then to stdout which gets redirected?"
That is correct

tee sends output to the specified file, and to stdout.
the last ">" redirects standout to the second file specified.